# Can I have an array that does not have a limit because I am getting my input by scanner?

Tags: java, arrays

Okay... I am trying to understand if I can do this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     double[] numbers = new double[5];

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
     {
         System.out.println("Please enter number");
         numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
     }
}
```

But I do not want it to be limited for 0-5. For example, I can take the user input of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

Is that possible? How is it done?

Comment: yeah it's called a container and Java has loads to choose from. Vector, ArrayList, you name it.

Comment: Arrays are not resizable. Can you use one of Java's many List implementations?

Comment: You want to use a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering values console, limitless and stored in an array:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        ArrayList<Double> numbers= new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Please enter number: ");           
        s=input.nextLine();
        String [] strnum = s.split("\\s+");

        int j=0;
        while(j<strnum.length){
            numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(strnum[j++]));
        }   
        for (Double n : numbers)
            System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache ArrayUtils lets you "add" new elements:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Creating a new array with the older and adding a new elment. Then you can do:

```
array = ArrayUtils.add(array, newElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ArrayList` class. The size of it will expand when you add new items.

Example usage:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(5);
int a = myList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are limited. You should use `ArrayList` class for it.

```
    import java.util.*;

//...

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Hello!");
list.add("How are you?");

System.out.println(list.get(0)); // prints "Hello!"

for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
} // prints "Hello!", "How are you?"
```

**OR**

```
 ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("String1");
strings.add("String2");

// To access a specific element:
System.out.println(strings.get(1));
// To loop through and print all of the elements:
for (String element : strings) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

The ArrayList class extends AbstractList and implements the List interface. ArrayList supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed.

Standard Java arrays are of a fixed length. After arrays are created, they cannot grow or shrink, which means that you must know in advance how many elements an array will hold.

Array lists are created with an initial size. When this size is exceeded, the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed, the array may be shrunk.

The ArrayList class supports three constructors. The first constructor builds an empty array list.

```
ArrayList( )
```

The following constructor builds an array list that is initialized with the elements of the collection c.

```
ArrayList(Collection c)
```

The following constructor builds an array list that has the specified initial capacity. The capacity is the size of the underlying array that is used to store the elements.

The capacity grows automatically as elements are added to an array list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @Integral its like this

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use this code bellow:

```
   ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList();
   boolean condition = true; 
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   while(condition){
       list.add(input.nextDouble());
       System.out.println("Do you want to continue Y/N ?");
       condition = (input.nextLine().charAt(0) == 'Y');
   }
```